# Why we use new keyword for initializing structure though it's a value type

Tags: c#, structure

Why do we use the `new` keyword for initializing a structure even though it's a value type in C#?

Answer (score 6):

Because that is the keyword that the language specification says you *use* to to initialize a value-type (via either a custom constructor or simply zeroing the memory (the parameterless `new()` usage on value-types), although there is an edge-case when even this is unnecessary). It would seem odd to add a *different* language keyword for the same concept. Even more-so if you consider generics:

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : new() // not terribly helpful, but....
{
    return new T();
}
```

If there were different keywords for reference-types and value-types, this would be very confusing for, say, `var zero = Create<int>()`. Again, the example is silly, but there is a point in there.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a struct object using the new operator, it gets created and the appropriate constructor is called.

But there is an exception. Structs can be instantiated without using the new operator. In such a case, there is no constructor call, which makes the allocation more efficient. However, the fields will remain unassigned and the object cannot be used until all of the fields are initialized.

For example:

```
public struct CoOrds
{
    public int x, y;

    public CoOrds(int p1, int p2)
    {
        x = p1;
        y = p2;
    }
}

 // Declare an 
 CoOrds coords1;

 // Initialize:
 coords1.x = 10;
 coords1.y = 20;
```

Comment: While true, this example is perhaps confusing because it shows a few very atypical features (public fields, mutable struct)

Comment: I hope the MSDN docs come with a usage warning, then (I found it, and *tried* to add some community content... we'll see ;p)